# How do I get the knee to bend the other direction?

Tags: pose-mode

[image]

I've set the pole target as child bone to the IK bone attached to the yellow bone which solved some problems. The knee now constantly bends in the exact opposite direction.
[image]

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

It rotates the foot. It something with rotation. In a video, I heard something about redirecting all axes, but couldn't find where because the given shortcut didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** After inspecting the file you provided, the issue is that the leg bones actually bend backwards at the knee very slightly. In this case, Blender will never make the point point the direction you want. If you pull the knee joint forward a bit, or even just make the leg bones perfectly in line the IK will work as expected.

In the IK constraint options, right by where you selected the pole target, there is a *Pole Angle* option that will change the angle of the bend in relation to the target. Since yours is simply backwards, setting it to 180 degrees should do the trick.

Comment: I post an answer. I couldn't insert a picture here and I don't know if your notified about whole new answers.

Comment: For future reference you can edit your question and add images there. In the answer you posted, I don't see the knee target in both images. Is it still there? Make sure you've reset all the bones in pose mode as well (alt-g,alt-r)

Comment: I had the pole target BEHIND the human for testing because it didn't work when it was in front of him. The bending direction is better now but not completely fixed. Problem 1: The mesh is twisted - the foot shall turn the other direction.
Problem 2: The knee doesn't rotate completely straight towards the pole target but twists the knee left or right.

Comment: So the first thing I would do is to have the pole target directly in front of the knee. It will not work well if it isn't. The pole angle will only change how the bones themselves rotate, so use it to point the knee bones directly at the pole target. If you want, you can upload your blend file and put the link in your question and I can take a look.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5846" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5846/)

Comment: I found the issue, and included it in my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Aww, that was so helpful! I would've been lost without you... Ima experiment further now or soon and I hope to have the basics completed soon, so I can be creative. The more I already know of the program, the more I can find out on my own.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. If you're satisfied with my answer, please accept it (the little green check mark on the left) so that future viewers know what worked without having to read the comments.